# How can I use random.sample & random.choice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use `random.sample` and `random.choice` to make a simple game.
What I want to do is get 8 words randomly from the `candidateWords` list (this list has 100 words) and then randomly pick 1 word out to be the answer.

Right now the `for` loop is showing all my words from the `candidateWords` list and at

```
one = random.choice(candidateWords)
```

is not picking the chosen word from the 8 words. I haven't able to generate 8 words in the first place so I know why this isn't working properly.

```
import random
candidateWords = ['AETHER', 'BADGED', 'BALDER', 'BANDED', 'BANTER', 'BARBER', 'BASHER', 'BATHED', 'BATHER', 'BEAMED', 'BEANED', 'BEAVER', 'BECKET', 'BEDDER', 'BEDELL', 'BEDRID', 'BEEPER', 'BEGGAR', 'BEGGED', 'BELIES', 'BELLES', 'BENDED', 'BENDEE', 'BETTER', 'BLAMER', 'BLOWER', 'BOBBER', 'BOLDER', 'BOLTER', 'BOMBER', 'BOOKER', 'BOPPER', 'BORDER', 'BOSKER', 'BOTHER', 'BOWYER', 'BRACER', 'BUDGER', 'BUMPER', 'BUSHER', 'BUSIER', 'CEILER', 'DEADEN', 'DEAFER', 'DEARER', 'DELVER', 'DENSER', 'DEXTER', 'EVADER', 'GELDED', 'GELDER', 'HEARER', 'HEIFER', 'HERDER', 'HIDDEN', 'JESTER', 'JUDDER', 'KIDDED', 'KIDDER', 'LEANER', 'LEAPER', 'LEASER', 'LEVIED', 'LEVIER', 'LEVIES', 'LIDDED', 'MADDER', 'MEANER', 'MENDER', 'MINDER', 'NEATER', 'NEEDED', 'NESTER', 'PENNER', 'PERTER', 'PEWTER', 'PODDED', 'PONDER', 'RADDED', 'REALER', 'REAVER', 'REEDED', 'REIVER', 'RELIER', 'RENDER', 'SEARER', 'SEDGES', 'SEEDED', 'SEISER', 'SETTER', 'SIDDUR', 'TEENER', 'TEMPER', 'TENDER', 'TERMER', 'VENDER', 'WEDDER', 'WEEDED', 'WELDED', 'YONDER']

def wordlist():
    for index, item in enumerate(random.sample(candidateWords, len(candidateWords))):
        print(index, ") ", item, sep='')

one = random.choice(candidateWords)

print("Welcome to the Guess-The-Word Game.\nThe Password is one of these words:")
wordlist()
print(one)
```

Comment: If you only want 8, why pass `len(candidateWords)` to `.sample`? And why do you pick `one` out of the full-length list, rather than the shorter list?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've figured out that if I type 8 instead of len() I can get 8 words from the list `for index, item in enumerate(random.sample(candidateWords, 8)): `
and for picking one chosen word is because that one word is going to be the answer from the 8 choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just follow the flow of your program as it executes one statement at a time.  First make the sample of 8 words, then choose one of those.

```
import random
candidateWords = [...]

def wordlist(words):
    for index, item in enumerate(words):
        print(index, ") ", item, sep='')

available_words = random.sample(candidateWords, 8)
one = random.choice( available_words )

print("Welcome to the Guess-The-Word Game.\nThe Password is one of these words:")
wordlist(available_words)
print(one)
```

Comment: Hi dsh, I think you've hit the jackpot for me!.
This is what I was trying to do. Because I am new to programming I still cant fully understand the flow but from reading your code I can understand what you have done. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just follow each statement in order: create a list, define a function, call a function and assign the result to a name, call a function and assign the result to a name, print a message, call a function, in that function iterate through the argument printing the items, return from the function, print an object. Apart from function calls, the statements are executed from top to bottom. Pay attention to assignments as these change what a name refers to.